# Making an image grow and a div to slide in on hover

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

I hope you can help or point me in the right direction.

I am trying to make a an image grow when I hover over it's parent DIV, but also have the background of the caption area slide in rather than fade in.

In the below example the entire panel increases, if I use the .grow style the image will only grow when I hover over the image, which isn't quite what I want.  Also I want it to be more over an overflow hidden affect (?).

This is the closest answer I can find but not quite.

Hope you can help!!

https://jsfiddle.net/SteveDavies/zezq2cb6/

```
    <!-- HTML -->

<div class="content container ">
  <div class="row">

    <a href="#" id="panel-effect">
      <div class=" front-panel col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="grow img-panel img-area-height" id="img1">
          </div>
          <div class="panel-txt-area">
            <p>blaaaaa</p>
            <div class="panel-title"><h3>TITLE &raquo;</h3></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
      <div class=" front-panel col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="img-panel img-area-height" id="img1">
          </div>
          <div class="panel-txt-area">
            <p>blaaaaa</p>
            <div class="panel-title"><h3>TITLE &raquo;</h3></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a href="#">
      <div class=" front-panel col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="img-panel img-area-height" id="img1">
          </div>
          <div class="panel-txt-area">
            <p>blaaaaa</p>
            <div class="panel-title"><h3>TITLE &raquo;</h3></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<!--container-->

<div style="margin-bottom:500px">
  <!--SPACER-->
</div>


<!-- CSS -->

.container{
  width:1270px;
}
body{
  background-color:#adafaf;
}

.front-panel{margin:0px 10px 10px 0px;}


.img-area-height{
  height:250px;
}

.panel-txt-area {
   height:180px;
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#000;
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
}

.panel-txt-area:hover{
  background-color:#9eab05;
    color:#fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

}

.panel-title{position:absolute;bottom:0;}

.img-panel {

  background-size:cover;
}

#img1{background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-c-640-480-9.jpg);}

/*
.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.grow:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }*/

#panel-effect{
display: block;
/*width: 300px;
height: 300px;*/
-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
-moz-transform: scale(1,1);
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
}
#panel-effect:hover{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05,1.07);
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
-moz-transform: scale(1.05,1.07);
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
position: relative;
z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please give the grow effect only for the background div. please Update the below ID styles in your style sheet.

```
#panel-effect .grow{
display: block;
/*width: 300px;
height: 300px;*/
-webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
-moz-transform: scale(1,1);
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
}
#panel-effect .grow:hover{
-webkit-transform: scale(1.05,1.07);
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
-moz-transform: scale(1.05,1.07);
-moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
position: relative;
z-index: 99;
}
```

Here are the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tdfrgxhg/)

Comment: Thanks, not quite, in the example the width of the image is bigger than the white area, I want it to stay the same but the background image to increase.

Answer (score 1):

check this fiddle..isthis what you need?

consider the following example

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">
  <img src="http://files.braadmartin.com/gretsch-catalina-club-in-natural.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
  <img src="http://files.braadmartin.com/gretsch-catalina-club-in-natural.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
</a>  
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
  <img src="http://files.braadmartin.com/gretsch-catalina-club-in-natural.jpg" width="250" height="250" />
</a>
</div>
```

and the css

```
 .wrapper {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper img {
  margin: 4% 0;
  height: 92%;
  width: auto;
}

.wrapper img:hover {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/65bpLp9y/

Comment: Not quite, say the image div is 300x300, I don't want the div to increase, just the image.  Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?: https://jsfiddle.net/2aLpw1hv/

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="panel-effect">
    <div class=" front-panel col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="grow img-panel img-area-height" id="img1"></div>
            <div class="panel-txt-area">
            <p>blaaaaa</p>
            <div class="panel-title">
                <h3>TITLE &raquo;</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.front-panel {
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.img-area-height {
  height: 250px;
}

.panel-txt-area {
  width: 800px;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 99;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #9eab05 50%, #fff 50%);
  -webkit-transition: background-position 1s;
  -moz-transition: background-position
}

#panel-effect:hover .panel-txt-area {
  background-position: 0 100%;
}

.panel-title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.img-panel {
  background-size: cover;
}

#img1 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/image_output/city-q-c-640-480-9.jpg);
}


/*
.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.grow:hover { transform: scale(1.1); }*/

#panel-effect .grow {
  /*width: 300px;
  height: 300px;*/
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
  -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
}

#panel-effect:hover .grow {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05, 1.07);
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
  -moz-transform: scale(1.05, 1.07);
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: So close, near perfect except I want the the white area to stay visible, and when I hover the green area will slide up behind.